# QVideoWidget doesn't show anything when aligned in a layout

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlayout, qvideowidget

I have a `QMediaPlayer`, `QVideoWidget` and some layout (ex. `QVboxLayout`).

The problem is when I add `QVideoWidget` with alignment specified — the video doesn't show up, there's only a place for the widget, a blank area with no video. And there's no problem if I add it without specifying alignment.

Here's the code example:

*Widget.h:*

```cpp
class Widget : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Widget(QWidget *parent = 0)
    : QWidget(parent)
  {
    QVideoWidget *vw = new QVideoWidget();
    QVBoxLayout *vb = new QVBoxLayout();
    vb->addWidget(vw, 0/*, Qt::AlignCenter*/); /// << here's the problem block
    this->setLayout(vb);

    QMediaPlayer *pl = new QMediaPlayer();
    pl->setMedia(QMediaContent(
                   QUrl::fromLocalFile("D:/1.wmv")));
    pl->setVideoOutput(vw);
    pl->play();
    this->resize(600, 480);
  }
  ~Widget() {}
};
```

If "qDebugging" `geometry()` of the video widget with center alignment "**off**" it looks like this:

```cpp
QRect(11,11 579x459)
```

But if I try to align it to the center it looks like this:

```cpp
QRect(300,240 0x0)
AlignLeft: *QRect(11,11 0x456)
```

It repeats even if I change `QVideoWidget` with `QGraphicsScene`, `QGraphicsView`, or `QGraphicsVideoItem` chain.

Comment: Just an idea. I had once a similar problem. A playing video stopped when I resized the window. Since you start the video in your constructor it might be the same problem. Try starting the video when your window has its final size, i.e. in resizeEvent().

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Greenflow, but it's not that problem. This example is just a simplest possible example, in the real program I use controls like Play, Pause, etc. and it doesn't help. 
By the way, there's sound going while the video does not. So. the problem is in widget, I guess.

Comment: Ok, then let me give you this additional piece of information... though I don't know if it is helpful: It is platform dependent. I tried your code under Linux and the film played. Regardless of Qt::AlignCenter.

Comment: @Greenflow that's sounds like a bug in Qt well then :-(
Did video worked fine with Qt::AlignCenter specified? I understood you right?

Comment: QtMultimedia uses 3rd party code to play video. gstreamer under Linux and depending on the Windows version Microsoft DirectShow **or** WMF. The one time I had to use multimedia on Linux **and** Windows I gave up and decided to use libvlc. Worked like a charm on all three platforms.

Comment: Oh, and yes... works with or without Qt::AlignCenter. I just copy/pasted your code and changed the movie file.

Comment: I don't think that the problem is in multimedia, @Greenflow. Please, look at my update to the question. Looks like the problem is wrong widget placement, but I can't figure out what is causing this to happen.

Comment: Wrong widget placement sounds strange. I am always willing to believe in a multimedia problem, but layouts? Bread and butter technique for qt for years. Almost all program use it in one or the other way. If there was a problem.... Nevertheless, nothing  can help you with. If I cannot reproduce this bug on my system... I cannot debug what I cannot see. Sorry. But where do you put the geometry debug? When I put it below this->resize(640,480) I always get QRect(0,0 640x480). Regardless of Qt::AlignCenter. Maybe it is my initial thought. Starting play before resize is done. Easy to get a race.

Comment: @Greenflow, geometry debug is in Widget::resizeEvent(...). By the way, I'm using Qt 5.4.0 Maybe our versions differs and that's why you can't reproduce it. 

Layout tries to center the left-top angle of the video widget, but not it's center. Also size sets up to 0x0 and even resize (in Widget::resizeEvent(..)) doesn't change geometry.

Comment: I use Qt 5.5 beta, but I doubt there are big differences in this part. But what it's interesting... When I put the debug in resizeEvent() I get: QRect(10,10 580x460) without Qt::AlignCenter and QRect(300,240 0x0) with Qt::AlignCenter. But in both cases the video plays. Just, as expected, the resizing behaviour is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the advice not to use alignment on widgets in layout, instead it's better to use alignment inside the widgets that have to be aligned.

That's why I've turned layout's alignment off, and centered the content of the widgets, that are inserted into the layout.

Looks like a hack, but it really works.