# No video and only audio output when restarting QMediaPlayer's media

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, ubuntu-20.04, qmediaplayer

I'm currently developing an application using Qt 5.15.2 on Ubuntu 22.04 and encountering an issue with `QMediaPlayer` in a video playback context. I've provided my code below for reference.

The application successfully plays, pauses, and resumes video playback.

However, when a video reaches its end and I attempt to restart it, only the audio resumes — the video display does not.

This issue occurs specifically after the video has completed playing, and I try to replay it.

```cpp
// videoPlayer function
void MainWindow::videoPlayer() {
    player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    videoWidget = new QVideoWidget(ui->widget_video);
    player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test.mp4"));

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(ui->widget_video);
    layout->addWidget(videoWidget, 0, Qt::AlignCenter);
    layout->setMargin(0);
    layout->setSpacing(0);
    ui->widget_video->setLayout(layout);
}

// Button click event handler
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_video_status_clicked() {
    switch (player->state()) {
    case QMediaPlayer::PlayingState:
        player->pause();
        break;
    case QMediaPlayer::PausedState:
        player->play();
        break;
    case QMediaPlayer::StoppedState:
        player->setPosition(0); // Reset to start
        player->play();
        break;
    default:
        player->play();
        break;
    }
}
```

I've tried resetting the media player's position and reinitializing the media source, but the issue persists. The audio resumes as expected, but the video display remains blank.

How can I solve this?

Comment: This seems related: [QVideoWidget doesn't show anything when aligned in a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728172/qvideowidget-doesnt-show-anything-when-aligned), and I've tested this using this [minimal example](https://hastebin.com/share/fadumijilo.cpp). I cannot figure out why exactly the alignment messes up the size, but I could only find 2 workarounds. See if this helps, and if that example reproduces your issue, use it in your question because it's easier to use.

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayeneMihoub ,As you mentioned, I think the problem stems from alignments. I updated my code according to your suggestions and the problem was solved. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @ysncck I seem to remember that in latest versions of Qt5 and early 6, QVideoWidget had issues due to its `sizeHint()` (and, possibly `minimumSizeHint()`) not returning a valid size respective to the video content. This is consistent with the `alignment` argument of `addWidget()` (which always uses the smaller size hint of the widget if the alignment is explicitly set, instead of trying to occupy the whole layout cell, as per documentation). I'd suggest you to check the Qt sources and consider using a QVideoWidget subclass that properly returns an acceptable size based on contents.

Answer (score 0):

I've now resolved this problem by directly placing the QVideoWidget in the parent widget, without using a layout. Here's the updated code:

```
void MainWindow::videoPlayer() {
    player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    video = new QVideoWidget; // Create a new QVideoWidget

    // Set the size and position of the QVideoWidget
    video->setGeometry(5, 5, ui->groupBox_videoPlayer->width() - 10, ui->groupBox_videoPlayer->height() - 10);
    video->setParent(ui->groupBox_videoPlayer); // Set the parent widget

    player->setVideoOutput(video); // Set the video output
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test.mp4")); // Load the media file

    video->setVisible(true); // Make the QVideoWidget visible
    video->show(); // Show the QVideoWidget
}
```

This change allows the video widget to be placed directly inside the parent widget, avoiding issues that arose from using a QVBoxLayout.

However, I couldn't understand why I was encountering problems when I used

QVBoxLayout.

Comment: This is not acceptable, for a lot of reasons. First of all, you're creating a direct child of the main window; then, if the window is resized, the video widget will never adjust its contents to the window size. For a standard case like this, the video widget **must** be the central widget or, at least, a child of it. It **may** work on your case probably because your backend uses video overlay, but doing it is just an assumption (and a terrible one).

Comment: https://hizliresim.com/eiuel0s
There is a structure like above.
The application will be used on a fixed screen size. It will remain constant at 1280*800 sizes.

I used nested stacked widgets to create navigation menus and submenus.

 In this case, how can I do it as you suggested? I'm a little confused at this part. I would really apreciate if you help.

@musicamante

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you're asking. Are you still having problems, or are you asking how to put QVideoWidget into "Video Playback Page"? Note that it's not clear from your original code if (1) `videoPlayer()` is called more than once, or if (2) `ui->widget_video` has a layout set in Designer. Both cases would be wrong anyway: the former is wrong as you should always check if a player already exists and eventually reuse it, while the latter is wrong because you cannot set a layout on a widget that already has one, which will be problematic in any case if you do (1) more than once.

Comment: Also, please use `@<username>` when replying to comments to your own posts (or whenever there are more than two users interacting), otherwise we will not be notified about replies.